# Can't call save() in Django Model? Gets: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, models

Thanks for the time for helping me out.

I'm pretty new to django and python.

So I have a model, that I'm trying to pull some data from another model to build out a landing page of sorts.  I was trying to make it completely customizatable in the admin but I discovered for what I wanted do I was going to have to involve AJAX.  I've scrapped that, and resorted to mostly removing the admin customization because this is really just for my own personal site.

So to boil down the overall goal:

- There are many "gallery" pages I want to pull the first image from
- Each gallery on my "landing" page will be a single image from each
  gallery, title, and url to the gallery.

This is part of my model:
    class AggeragateImages(Orderable):

```
    aggeragate = models.ForeignKey("AggeragatePage", related_name="thumbnails")
    gallery_titles = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=1000)
    gallery_slug = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=1000)

    def getGallery():
        """
        Returns PK of all Gallery content type pages
        """
        galleryPK = []

        for e in Page.objects.filter(content_model='gallery'):
            galleryPK.append(e.pk)

        return galleryPK

    galleryPK = getGallery()

    for e in galleryPK:
        gallery_titles = Gallery.objects.get(pk=e).titles
        gallery_titles.save()
        gallery_slug = Gallery.objects.get(pk=e).slug
        gallery_slug.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However why I run a syncdb I get: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'save'

I've also trying doing this through the interactive shell to, and I get the same error when calling 'save()'

Am I really far off base?  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at:

```
gallery_titles = Gallery.objects.get(pk=e).titles
gallery_titles.save()
```

When you do `Gallery.objects.get(pk=e)`, it returns you a model instance, however then you retrieve it's `titles` attribute which I guess is a string (`unicode`). So at that point, `gallery_titles` is a sting which you try to save on the next line, but `unicode` class does not have a method `save` which causes an error.

As a side note, it's probably not the best idea to put logic code directly inside a class definition. You can factor your logic into class methods which would be much more appropriate. When you call a class method inside it's definition you are still defining a class attribute.

Comment: do you have a suggested route I should take with saving the unicode as an object?

Comment: Look how you can efficiently utilize Foreign Keys in Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects